# Checking for Subgraph Respecting Node Labels

Tags: networkx, pytorch-geometric

I have two graphs G and S. Each graph takes discrete labels on the nodes. I want to check if S is a subgraph of G in the sense that there is an injective map, mapping nodes in S to G such that the edges are preserved and the node labels as well.

Sofar I have seen the VF2 algorithm in Networkx (https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html) but that method seems to not support the preservation of node labels.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if each node and edge in S exist in G.

```
import networkx as nx


def is_subgraph(S, G):
    if set(list(S.nodes)).issubset(list(G.nodes)) and \
       set(list(S.edges)).issubset(list(G.edges)):
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

S = nx.complete_graph(5)
G = nx.complete_graph(10)
H = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.1)

print(is_subgraph(S, G))
# True

print(is_subgraph(S, H))
# False
```